# Using PersistentManager to manage active sessions

Tags: java, tomcat

I want my Java application, which is running on Tomcat, to allow only 2 active sessions. I have that configured in the following excerpt from my *context.xml* shown below.

```
...
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" 
         saveOnRestart="false"
         maxActiveSessions="2">
    <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore"/>
</Manager>
...
```

That seems to work, as upon my third login (by using 3 separate browsers) I get an error:

```
org.apache.catalina.session.TooManyActiveSessionsException: createSession: Too many active sessions.
```

The problem is that after I reach that max, that error continues to recur - even after I logout and close all my browsers. How do I further configure my *context.xml* to clear out the number of sessions in Tomcat in order to be able to login again?

Comment: Hm, did you try to set processExpiresFrequency? Default is 6, you can try to set it to 1 to ask Tomcat to check sessions often. Docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: Thanks, Victor Bjorn. I tried adding that and unfortunately so far, still no luck. Still get the same error, even when I log out of the other sessions.

Comment: I don't know what version of Tomcat you use but can you try to set checkInterval="1" for the <Store> ? The reference for Tomcat 7 says that the default interval is 60 seconds: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html There's the old book with examples: https://books.google.ru/books?id=vJttHyVF0SUC&lpg=PA74&ots=i1byuZpRdZ&dq=FileStore%20checkInterval&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=FileStore%20checkInterval&f=false

So I'd play with settings examples from the docs/books and check for available logging solutions to see what happens.

Comment: Great. Thanks, Victor! Do you know if there's also a way to configure Tomcat to limit the number of sessions that can be started for each individual user?

Comment: So, did checkInterval make a trick? Regarding limitation you're asking - what's the goal to do it? Are you using any framework in your app? I'm asking because there are different ways to reach such a goal: from firewalls and apache HTTP server to Spring Boot solution.